# match all elements by class except undefined

Tags: jquery

Having table

```
 <table>
  <tr><td></td><td class="foo"></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td class="bar"></td></tr>
 </table>
```

**How to get all `td` elements having any class set?**

While trying

```
$.each($("td:not(undefined)"),function(i,v){ ...
```

i still get `undefined` class in result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$("td[class]").each(function(i,v){ ...
```

The attribute selector selects elements with the given attribute see [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).

As pimvdb pointed out `[class!='']` will filter out elements which have no classes but has the `class` attribute (i.e. an empty `class` attribute). Also, you can use `.each` directly on a jQuery set.

Also see [the selectors specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

Comment: `[class!='']` is more robust. If you remove all classes, an empty attribute is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $td = $('td').filter(function(){
              return this.className != ""
          })
```